# Make DOM Element visible without id attribute

Tags: selenium, firefox, phantomjs, visibility

Using cssSelector , I am able to find some elements which have id attribute. For example:

```
li[id='header-mypage-top']>a
```

and using isDisplayed() from Selenium 2 (WebDriver), it is found as true.

My problem is to click some of the links like below, which I am able to find using xpath but found false using isDisplayed().

```
<li class="logout" data-action-url="www.xxx.co.jp/yyy">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">ログアウト</a>
</li>
```

I tried to find using following code:

```
List<WebElement> elements =     driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='logout']/a"));
System.out.println("Logout item size: "+elements.size());
```

The size is shown as 1, but isDisplayed() returns false.

How I can make this element visible and be able to click it?

I am using PhantomJS 2.1.1. The above problem does not happen for Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='logout']/a")));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='logout']/a")));
```

Using the above two waits togather solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the element (in this case, "logout") is not loaded properly with the specific time. So you can use explicit wait as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='logout']/a")));
        boolean isLogoutDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='logout']/a")).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Is Logout displayed: " + isLogoutDisplayed);
```

Comment: I had the WebDriverWait like this: wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);

Comment: You can try with the following xpath:
//a[text()='ログアウト']